# Calling my app from Navigation's deeplink causes my fragment to be instantiad several times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm encoutering a very weird problem, when I start the app from the launcher everything is good, but when I start it from a link (in Messenger), the fragment's onCreate/OnCreateView... are called multiple time (but not the activity's)
I have a deep link set to my fragment :

```
<deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="https://www.mywebsite.com/invitation/{groupId}" />
```

I'm using Android Navigation Component :
app's build :

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
def nav_version = "2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

Main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Logger.d("ok that s weird");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Logger.addLogAdapter(new AndroidLogAdapter());
    }
}
```

My fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        apiService=NetworkingManager.getRetrofit().create(ApiService.class);
        student = WelcomeFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getStudent();
        Logger.d("welcomefragment view being created");
        return v;
    }
        }
```

My navigation graph : 
[image]

as you can see Fragment perform create is called twice... and in parallel I guess

Comment: What log message do you get if you use `FragmentManager.setEnableLogging(true)` before the `super.onCreate()` in your Activity?

Comment: I have modified the post with the results, btw I have replaced my test fragment with WelcomeFragment

Comment: Seems like a consequence of your `AuthenticationFragment` - does it call `navigate()` itself? Authentication shouldn't be the start destination of your graph, but should be handled separately as per the [conditional navigation docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#user_login)

Comment: yes it does, I never heard of conditional navigation before, thanks a lot !

Comment: I am facing the same issue..
But this is happening only once when I launch application from android studio ..
After that if I open from launcher then its not creating multiple instance ...

Answer (score 1):

New solution:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        navController.popBackStack(R.id.home, false)
        setIntent(intent)
        handleDeepLink()
    }
```

Do the above step in onNewIntent of you MainActivity or where you handle deeplinks.

Not sure if it's good practive @ianhanniballake